# How to get JSONB array index

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm sure there's a simple answer to this but I just can't find it. I need to obtain JSON array elements as rows, but their index is relevant for the subsequent processing. Here's a [very simplified] example:

```
id  content                                                 
--  ------------------------------------------------------------------
80  {"id":"107-80", "Sections": [{"parts":5},{"parts":8},{"parts":4}]}
```

I need to get:

```
id section section_content 
-- ------- --------------- 
80 0       {"parts":5}     
80 1       {"parts":8}     
80 2       {"parts":4}
```

I've tried:

```
select
  id,
  row_number() over() - 1 as section, 
  jsonb_array_elements(content -> 'Sections') as section_content
from purchase
```

But the `section` column is not computed correctly, as shown below:

```
id  section  section_content 
--- -------- --------------- 
80  0        {"parts":5}     
80  0        {"parts":8}     
80  0        {"parts":4}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `with ordinality`

```
select p.id, s.*
from purchase p
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(p.content -> 'Sections') with ordinality as s(section_content, section)
```

Comment: Will need to study the *SQL Standard* `ORDINALITY` clause. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use as CTE for that

> ```
> CREATE TABLE purchase (
>   "id" INTEGER,
>   "content" JSONB
> );
>
> INSERT INTO purchase
>   ("id", "content")
> VALUES
>   ('80', '{"id":"107-80", "Sections": [{"parts":5},{"parts":8},{"parts":4}]}');
> ```

> ```
> WITH CTE AS (select
>   id,
>   jsonb_array_elements(content -> 'Sections') as section_content
> from purchase)
> SELECT
> id,  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
>       PARTITION BY id)  as section, section_content FROM CTE
> ```
>
> ```
> id | section | section_content
> -: | ------: | :--------------
> 80 |       1 | {"parts": 5}   
> 80 |       2 | {"parts": 8}   
> 80 |       3 | {"parts": 4}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cfab32df4fdd7267c1f2d4f937330264)*

Comment: I'm curious how the row number is assigned correcly in the absence of `ORDER BY`. It nevertheless works.

Comment: window function take the the order that is given in the CTE, that is why it is working, i was more currios why your query doesn't work, it seems, that jsonb_array_elements  creates new rows without going to the pat where the window part recognozes  it